How to delete keytar password from pc when uninstall the electron applicatoin
I have created an electron application, and my electron application stores passwords in the keytar application, but when I uninstall the application, it does not clear the keytar value from the PC.
I used Electron Builder to create MSIS and NSIS applications, but it is not working. I login to my application, then store my password in Keytar, and when I uninstall the application, the keytar values stay stored.

i used electron-store instead of keytar and add property of deleteAppDataOnUninstall : true in nsis {package.json} and now my login cred. are delete when i uninstall the application , but if anyone know how to clear the keytar value please share the reference or links of solution
